# How to transfer a value from a string to another class

Tags: java, mysql, database, string, intellij-idea

I am writing my first code and i have some issues with transferring a value from a string (String Role) to another class.

Below you see a piece of my code i have written.

```
public void verifyLogin() {

        DatabaseConnection connectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectNow.getConnection();

        String verifyLogin = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE username = '" + enterUsername.getText() + "'AND password = '" + enterPassword.getText() + "'";

        try{
            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(verifyLogin);


            {
                if (queryResult.next()){

                    String Role = (queryResult.getString(5));
                    System.out.println(Role);

                    validateLogin();


                }else{
                    loginMessageLabel.setText("Onjuiste gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord");
                }
            }queryResult.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The reason of transferring the value is because in the other class i want to use the value of an if function, for making buttons/images (FXML) invisible.

Thanks for your help.

Piece of code of the second Class

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    //Welkom bericht

    String AB = AccountNameLabel.getText();
    System.out.println(AB);

    //Zichtbaar maken van afbeeldingen in applicatie
    File brandingFile = new File("images/logo.png");
    Image brandingImage = new Image(brandingFile.toURI().toString());
    brandingImageView.setImage(brandingImage);

    File LoginFile = new File("images/icon.png");
    Image LoginImage = new Image(LoginFile.toURI().toString());
    LoginImageView.setImage(LoginImage);

    File CalendarFile = new File("images/KalenderAanvraag.png");
    Image CalendarImage = new Image(CalendarFile.toURI().toString());
    CalenderImageView.setImage(CalendarImage);

    File OverviewFile = new File("images/KalenderOverzicht.png");
    Image OverviewImage = new Image(OverviewFile.toURI().toString());
    OverviewImageView.setImage(OverviewImage);

    if (AB.contains("Tester")){
    File DeleteUserFile = new File("images/Verwijderen.png");
    Image DeleteUserImage = new Image(DeleteUserFile.toURI().toString());
    DeleteUserImageView.setImage(DeleteUserImage);
    DeleteUserImageView.setVisible(false);

    File AddUserFile = new File("images/AccountToevoegen.png");
    Image AddUserImage = new Image(AddUserFile.toURI().toString());
    AddUserImageView.setImage(AddUserImage);
    AddUserImageView.setVisible(false);

    }else{

        File DeleteUserFile = new File("images/Verwijderen.png");
        Image DeleteUserImage = new Image(DeleteUserFile.toURI().toString());
        DeleteUserImageView.setImage(DeleteUserImage);

        File AddUserFile = new File("images/AccountToevoegen.png");
        Image AddUserImage = new Image(AddUserFile.toURI().toString());
        AddUserImageView.setImage(AddUserImage);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for this other class?  The answer depends on the code in that class.

Comment: You should be using statement parameters. Gluing user input directly into your query leaves you open to SQL injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @markspace I have added the code of the other class. Thanks!